# What's the benefit of Rails asset pipeline for images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Asset Pipeline is made up of 3 processes - precompile, concatenation, and minification.

I understand that JavaScript and CSS can benefit from it. However, I can't think of any benefits for images.

Can you explain it, please?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use Rails helpers for images (e.g. `image_tag`), versioning/fingerprining is the primary benefit.

The fingerprinting helps to bust cache (both from a CDN and browser perspective).

See this [rails guide section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care).

Answer (score 1):

One benefit to passing images through the Rails asset pipeline is to take advantage of asset fingerprinting, which lets you set far-future caching headers and busts the cache when the asset changes.

> When a filename is unique and based on its content, HTTP headers can be set to encourage caches everywhere (whether at CDNs, at ISPs, in networking equipment, or in web browsers) to keep their own copy of the content. When the content is updated, the fingerprint will change. This will cause the remote clients to request a new copy of the content. This is generally known as cache busting. ( from the [Ruby on Rails Guides: Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care))

Answer (score 1):

#### When rendering SVG files in your Ruby CSS files

```
Example
.benefits__icon::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("learn-investment-investxd.svg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 52px;
}
```

with an **assets.rb** file as such

```
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.css dashboard.css dashboard.js)` with no other configuration.
```

The example above, the background url would restore to `http://localhost:3001/learn-investment-investxd.png` even if I place the **image** file `learn-investment-investxd.png` in my **assets/images** folder.

#### My workaround

> I added `assets` to the **url**.

```
.benefits__icon::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("assets/learn-investment-investxd.svg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 52px;
}
```

**This works.**
It can be improved