# How to integrate minifier/optimizer for images into asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, asset-pipeline

Let's say there is a shell script that will minify any give image files (png, gif, jpeg etc).  And I'd like to run that as a part of the production deployment process, integrating into Asset Pipeline.  1) is it feasible? 2) how do I do it?  Like " [What's the benefit of Rails asset pipeline for images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462712/whats-the-benefit-of-rails-asset-pipeline-for-images) " question, I only see asset pipeline for images as adding a hash value for each image, which makes sense, but doesn't give me a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment script could call a rake task that would run the shell script to compress the images before the deploy happens.

Comment: I thought it could be a fairly simple and popular task, but I was probably wrong about it.